# Webcambild/Webcambilder/Webcambildern: Image and/or video?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, noun

Does Webcambild/Webcambilder/Webcamdern refer to a webcam that only shows images or can it refer to a webcam that shows streaming video?

eg: "Gegenstand dieses Vertrages ist die Bereitstellung von Webcambildern"

Comment: If a video was meant, or even a live video, this had to be mentioned in my view. But a judge would decide. Given judges aren't tech-savvy …

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, a webcam video is the recording or broadcasting of multiple visual images made in digital format. Therefore and without any further information or context ... it can be **both**, but reading the contract's details will most likely tell you exactly what its about.

Answer (score 0):

- **Webcambild**
  One picture (image), taken with a webcam
  Alternate meaning: An image showing a webcam
- **Webcambilder**
  Two or more pictures (images), taken with a webcam
  (Two or more images showng webcams)
- **Webcamdern**
  Not a German word, i.e. this words means nothing

> Gegenstand dieses Vertrages ist die Bereitstellung von Webcambildern.
>   Subject of this contract is the provision of webcam **images.**